# How to prevent labels overlapping in ggplot stacked barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

Given are these two data sets, `df_bars` and `df_lines`:

```
library (ggplot2)
library (ggtext)

df_bars <-
  structure(
    list(
      col1 = structure(
        c(
          1L,
          2L,
          3L,
          4L,
          5L,
          6L,
          7L,
          8L,
          9L,
          10L,
          11L,
          12L,
          1L,
          2L,
          3L,
          4L,
          5L,
          6L,
          7L,
          8L,
          9L,
          10L,
          11L,
          12L,
          1L,
          2L,
          3L,
          4L,
          5L,
          6L,
          7L,
          8L,
          9L,
          10L,
          11L,
          12L,
          1L,
          2L,
          3L,
          4L,
          5L,
          6L,
          7L,
          8L,
          9L,
          10L,
          11L,
          12L,
          1L,
          2L,
          3L,
          4L,
          5L,
          6L,
          7L,
          8L,
          9L,
          10L,
          11L,
          12L
        ),
        levels = c(
          "AAA\nN =  172",
          "BBB",
          "CCC",
          "DDD",
          "EEE",
          "FFF",
          "GGG",
          "HHH",
          "III",
          "JJJ",
          "KKK",
          "LLL"
        ),
        class = c("ordered",
                  "factor")
      ),
      Status = structure(
        c(
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          1L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          2L,
          3L,
          3L,
          3L,
          3L,
          3L,
          3L,
          3L,
          3L,
          3L,
          3L,
          3L,
          3L,
          4L,
          4L,
          4L,
          4L,
          4L,
          4L,
          4L,
          4L,
          4L,
          4L,
          4L,
          4L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L
        ),
        levels = c("x", "aaa.kp", "bbb.kp",
                   "ccc.kp", "ddd.kp"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      Values = c(
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        NA,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0.0813953488372093,
        0.226744186046512,
        0.36046511627907,
        0.447674418604651,
        0.476744186046512,
        0.476744186046512,
        NA,
        0.941860465116279,
        0.831395348837209,
        0.738372093023256,
        0.703488372093023,
        0.680232558139535,
        0.581395348837209,
        0.418604651162791,
        0.273255813953488,
        0.186046511627907,
        0.151162790697674,
        0.0523255813953488,
        NA,
        0,
        0,
        0.0406976744186047,
        0.0406976744186047,
        0.0523255813953488,
        0.0523255813953488,
        0.0581395348837209,
        0.0581395348837209,
        0.0581395348837209,
        0.0581395348837209,
        0.0581395348837209,
        NA,
        0.0581395348837209,
        0.168604651162791,
        0.22093023255814,
        0.255813953488372,
        0.267441860465116,
        0.284883720930233,
        0.296511627906977,
        0.308139534883721,
        0.308139534883721,
        0.313953488372093,
        0.412790697674419
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, -60L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )


df_lines <-
  structure(
    list(
      col1 = structure(
        1:12,
        levels = c(
          "AAA\nN =  172",
          "BBB",
          "CCC",
          "DDD",
          "EEE",
          "FFF",
          "GGG",
          "HHH",
          "III",
          "JJJ",
          "KKK",
          "LLL"
        ),
        class = c("ordered",
                  "factor")
      ),
      aaa.l.rev = c(
        NA,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0.968604651162791,
        0.854651162790698,
        0.866279069767442,
        0.912790697674419,
        0.97093023255814,
        1
      ),
      eee.l = c(
        NA,
        0.0381395348837209,
        0.09046511627907,
        0.0930232558139535,
        0.0348837209302326,
        0.0232558139534884,
        0.0174418604651163,
        0.0174418604651163,
        0.0116279069767442,
        0,
        0.00581395348837209,
        0.0988372093023256
      )
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, -12L)
  )
```

I create a stacked bar chart, which is OK so far. Here I also display the value labels.

In addition, there are two lines where the value labels are also displayed.

```
    ggplot(df_bars, aes(x = col1, y = Values)) +
  geom_bar(
    data = df_bars,
    mapping = aes(x = col1, y = Values, fill = Status),
    position = "stack",
    stat = "identity"
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = df_bars,
    aes(
      x = col1,
      y = Values,
      geom = Status,
      label = ifelse(Values >= 0.01, paste0 (sprintf(
        "%1.1f%%", 100 * Values
      )), "")
    ),
    size = 2.5,
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
    color = (farbe <- c("white", rep(c(
      "black"
    ), times = 55)))
  ) +
  geom_line(data = df_lines,
            mapping = aes(
              x = col1,
              y = eee.l,
              group = 1,
              colour = "Lorem"
            )) +
  geom_line(data = df_lines,
            mapping = aes(
              x = col1,
              y = aaa.l.rev,
              group = 1,
              colour = "Ipsum"
            )) +
  geom_text(
    data = df_lines,
    mapping = aes(
      x = col1,
      y = aaa.l.rev,
      label = ifelse(aaa.l.rev >= 0.1, paste0 (sprintf(
        "%1.1f%%", -100 * aaa.l.rev + 100
      )), "")
    ),
    size = 2.5,
    position = position_stack(vjust = .98)
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = df_lines,
    mapping = aes(
      x = col1,
      y = eee.l,
      label = paste0 (sprintf("%1.1f%%", 100 * eee.l))
    ),
    size = 2.5,
    position = position_stack(vjust = .9)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(NA, 100),
                     labels = NULL) +
  labs(title = "Title\n\n", colour = "") +
  labs(caption = paste(
    sprintf("**Bla/Blubb**: %s", "Blubb"),
    sprintf("\n\n**As of**: %s", format(Sys.time(), "%b %Y"))
  )) +
  ylab ("") + xlab ("") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = df_bars$col1, position = "top") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "")) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.box = "vertical",
    legend.box.just = "left",
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.2, 'cm'),
    legend.box.spacing = unit(0, "pt"),
    legend.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 7, color = "black"),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "#EAEAEA"),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "#EAEAEA"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white",
                                   color = "#EAEAEA"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA),
    plot.title = element_textbox(
      size = 11,
      lineheight = 1,
      face = "bold",
      width = unit(0.9, "npc"),
    ),
    plot.margin = margin(0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, "cm"),
    plot.caption.position = "plot",
    plot.caption = element_textbox(
      size = 7,
      lineheight = 1.2,
      hjust = 0.3,
      vjust = 0.5,
      width = unit(1.02, "npc"),
      margin = margin(12, 0, 0, 2)
    ),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 7, color = "black")
  )
```

In some places the value labels of the bars and the lines overlap. Is there a way to avoid this automatically?

[image]

Comment: The `ggrepel` package is my go-to for automatically separating overlapped labels.

Comment: One workaround I can think of is to add the line data to the bar data then plot them as invisible bars or the same pink color like in your plot. That way you will only need one `geom_text()`  line and control the overlapping. Also take a look at `geom_bartext()` in https://erocoar.github.io/ggpol/ and `geom_bar_text()` in https://wilkox.org/ggfittext/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches.

First, a quick and dirty workaround would be to left-align one set of labels and right-align the other. Here I added `hjust = 1.1` to the `geom_text()` call for the bars, and `fontface = "bold", hjust = -0.1` to the 2 `geom_text()` calls for the lines (stealing @JonSpring's idea of bolding the line labels). All other code is unchanged.

[image]

The labeling still isn't exactly intuitive. If you really want to show percentages for both the lines and bars, consider adding interactivity. For instance, you could show static labels for the lines, and labels for the bar segment in tooltips. Using ggiraph:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(ggiraph)

p <- ggplot(df_bars, aes(x = col1, y = Values)) +
  geom_bar_interactive(
    mapping = aes(
      fill = Status, 
      tooltip = ifelse(Values >= 0.01, paste0(sprintf("%1.1f%%", 100 * Values)), ""),
      data_id = paste(col1, Status)
    ),
    position = "stack",
    stat = "identity"
  ) +
  # remove following geom_text() call
  geom_line(
    # rest of plot code as in OP
    # ...

girafe(
  ggobj = p,
  options = list(opts_hover("filter:brightness(120%);"))
)
```

Screenshot of hovering over the green section of the `"FFF"` bar:

[image]

Comment: Nice, alignment strikes me as a very intuitive way to distinguish them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach replacing the three geom_text layers, combining them so that they can avoid each other, and replicating the positioning using dplyr. I've tried here to make the labels a little more distinguished from one another by using bold for the line labels, but there are surely other ways you might distinguish them (e.g. color, label outline, size, fontface, etc.)

[image]

```
# after loading library(dplyr) as well
...


 ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
    aes(col1, Values_pos, label = label, fontface = fontface),
    direction = "y",
    box.padding = 0.1, label.padding = 0.1, 
    size = 2.5,
    data = bind_rows(
      df_bars %>% 
        arrange(Status) %>%
        group_by(col1) %>%
        arrange(desc(Status)) %>%
        mutate(Values_cuml = cumsum(Values),
               Values_pos = Values_cuml - Values/2,
               fontface = "plain",
               label = ifelse(Values >= 0.01, paste0 (sprintf(
                 "%1.1f%%", 100 * Values
               )), "")) %>%
        ungroup(),
      
      df_lines %>%
        group_by(col1) %>%
        mutate(Values_cuml = cumsum(aaa.l.rev),
               Values_pos = Values_cuml - 0.02*aaa.l.rev,
               fontface = "bold",
               label = ifelse(aaa.l.rev >= 0.1, paste0 (sprintf(
                 "%1.1f%%", -100 * aaa.l.rev + 100
               )), "")) %>%
        ungroup(),
      
      df_lines %>%
        group_by(col1) %>%
        mutate(Values_cuml = cumsum(eee.l),
               Values_pos = Values_cuml - 0.1*eee.l,
               fontface = "bold",
               label = paste0 (sprintf("%1.1f%%", 100 * eee.l))) %>%
        ungroup()
    )
  ) +
```